# Using lodash throttle with React text input and Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, lodash, throttling

I'm struggling to make this text input throttle work in react even after reading lots of docs.

```
import { throttle } from 'lodash';
...
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={(e): void => throttle(handleTextInput, 1000)(e)}
      />
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong, any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you are calling `throttle` function while defining onChange for the input. You have to give a function to the `throttle` which needs to be called after the wait. Try this -

```
throttledInput = throttle(input => this.handleTextInput(input), 1000);
...
<input
   type="text"
   onChange={(e) => this.throttledInput(e.target.value);}
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

The `e` is syntactically false in your code example. Change your code to the above and tell me if it was successful.

```
<input type="text"
       onChange={() => throttle(handleTextInput, 1000)}
/>
```